# Error converting data type varchar to numeric c# Application

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a SQL Server database table which I am using my C# application to connect to SQL, look at the table and return values into the textbox on my form. However, when I click the button, I get the following error :

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric c# Application

My code is here:

```
private void buttonFilter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            sqlCon.Open();

            SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(string.Format(
                "SELECT {0} FROM {1} WHERE {2} = " + SearchBox.Text.ToString(), 
                 ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SQLFirst3FieldResults"],
                 ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SQLTableName"],
                 ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SQLSearchColumn"]), sqlCon);

            DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
            sqlDa.Fill(dtbl);

            debtTypeResult.Text = dtbl.Rows[0][0].ToString();
            customerNameResult.Text = dtbl.Rows[0][1].ToString();
            customerIDResult.Text = dtbl.Rows[0][2].ToString();

            label1.Visible = true;
            label2.Visible = true;
            label3.Visible = true;
            debtTypeResult.Visible = true;
            customerNameResult.Visible = true;
            customerIDResult.Visible = true;
            button1.Visible = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you don't use sql parameters? `SELECT {0} FROM {1} WHERE {2} = " + SearchBox.Text.ToString()` is an invitation for sql injection.

Comment: Where do you get the exception, at `sqlDa.Fill(dtbl)`?

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: hi @MarioMitterbauer , Arithmetic Overflow the error is Error converting data type varchar to numeric

Comment: Hi @Rango that is correct when i get to  sqlDa.Fill(dtbl); it errors out

Comment: @Jackz please put the exact error code in your question (edit).

Comment: @MarioMitterbauer i dont get an error code only that error message

Comment: @Jackz please share the whole message with us

Comment: @MarioMitterbauer that is the whole message

Comment: Does the column in your `WHERE` clause hold numeric values or text? Might be as simple as putting single quotes around your search criteria  `WHERE [column] = '...'` - and please, please use a parametrized query.

Comment: @LocEngineerThank you that works great!

Comment: @LocEngineer how do i add ' ' to my textbox so the user doesn't have to?

Comment: @LocEngineer - If you use parameters as recommended, you won't have to worry about adding ''.

Answer (score 3):

First your code with the minimal correction of surrounding the search value with quotes:

```
SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(string.Format(
                "SELECT {0} FROM {1} WHERE {2} = '" + SearchBox.Text.ToString() + "'", 
                 ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SQLFirst3FieldResults"],
                 ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SQLTableName"],
                 ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SQLSearchColumn"]), sqlCon);

            DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();

            sqlDa.Fill(dtbl);
```

This approach, however, is not recommendable at all, since

- it leaves you open to SQL injection
- you have to manually check and handle quotes/apostrophes in the search string

It is recommended you use parameters wherever possible. It is safer and the query doesn't break if you search for values with single quotes in them:

```
SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter($"SELECT {ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SQLFirst3FieldResults"]} FROM {ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SQLTableName"]} WHERE {ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SQLSearchColumn"]} = @which", sqlCon);

sqlDa.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@which", SearchBox.Text.ToString());

DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
sqlDa.Fill(dtbl);
```

Comment: I didn't think column names could be parameterized?

Comment: To be honest: I couldn’t test. Now that you mention it, I’m no longer sure either. Will test tomorrow and adapt if needed.

Comment: Good catch, @ChrisDunaway. Edited.